# How to extract the key values from a function within a function using list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have the data on movies, which looks like this for one of the movies, Bridesmaids.

```
{'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': 'Bridesmaids', 'Type': 'movie'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'Baby Mama', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The Five-Year Engagement', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Bachelorette', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The Heat', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Date Night', 'Type': 'movie'}]}}
```

I want to create a list[] which contains the names of movies only (so, I want to descend into `'Similar'`, then `'Info'`, within the dictionary, find the value for the `'Name'` key, extract this value, `e.g.'Bridesmaids'`) and iterate for all of the movies.

first I created the function get_movies_from_tastedive(name), to have my data on movies (Part 1).

Then I am trying to define a second function, extract_movie_titles, which hopefully will return a list of movie titles.  I'm using list comprehension here.
When I try to invoke it by printing (line 22 and line 23), it does not work..

Part 1.

```
def get_movies_from_tastedive(name):
    baseurl = 'https://tastedive.com/api/similar'
    pdict = {'q': name,'type': 'movies','limit': '5'}
    movie_resp = requests.get(baseurl, params = pdict)
    return movie_resp.json()
```

Part 2.

```
def extract_movie_titles(name):
p = get_movies_from_tastedive(name)   
return[d['Name'] for d in p['Similar']['Info']]

print(extract_movie_titles(get_movies_from_tastedive("Tony Bennett"))) #line 22
print(extract_movie_titles(get_movies_from_tastedive("Bridesmaids"))) #line 23
```

> SyntaxError: bad input on line 22

Comment: Change `d[Name]` to `d['Name']`. You've missed quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A compacted version of the code plus a short testing code.

```
import requests


def get_movies_from_tastedive(name):
    r = requests.get('https://tastedive.com/api/similar', params={'q': name, 'type': 'movies', 'limit': '5'})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return [m['Name'] for m in r.json()['Similar']['Results'] if m['Type'] == 'movie']


movies = get_movies_from_tastedive('Tony Bennett')
if movies:
    print(movies)
else:
    print('ERR.Cant read movies')
```

Output

```
['The Startup Kids', 'The Englishman Who Went Up A Hill But Came Down A Mountain', 'A Place In The Sun', 'Last Tango In Paris', 'Charlie Chaplin']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
import requests_with_caching
import json 

def get_movies_from_tastedive(string):
    baseurl="https://tastedive.com/api/similar"
    params_diction={}
        
    params_diction["q"]=string
    params_diction["type"]="movies"
    params_diction["limit"]=5 
    taste_dive_resp = requests_with_caching.get(baseurl, params = params_diction)
    return taste_dive_resp.json()
```